# Force protractor's onPrepare to wait for async http request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, asynchronous, protractor

My protractor conf.js,`onPrepare` function needs to make a http request that looks like,

```
onPrepare: function(done) {
    request.get('http://pepper/sysid')
      .end(function(err, resp){
        if(err || !resp.ok){
          log("there is an error " + err.message)
          done()
        }else{
          global.sysid = resp.sysid
          done()
         }
      })
```

It throws error as,`done is not a function`

Is there any other way, that i can force the callback inside `onPrepare` to be invoked before my tests start execution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`onPrepare()` can [optionally return a promise](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/827554148d2af8e3dc1fdeb4481bfb906a98d116/docs/system-setup.md#setting-up-the-system-under-test) that protractor would resolve before starting to execute the tests:

> `onPrepare` can optionally return a promise, which Protractor will wait
>   for before continuing execution. This can be used if the preparation
>   involves any asynchronous calls, e.g. interacting with the browser.
>   Otherwise Protractor cannot guarantee order of execution and may start
>   the tests before preparation finishes.

Make a protractor `promise` and return it from `onPrepare()`:

```
onPrepare: function() {
    var defer = protractor.promise.defer();

    request.get('http://pepper/sysid').end(function(err, resp) {
        if (err || !resp.ok) {
            log("there is an error " + err.message);
            defer.reject(resp);
        } else {
            global.sysid = resp.sysid;
            defer.fulfill(resp);
        }
    });

    return defer.promise;
},
```