# Protractor not waiting for angular2 to load

Tags: angular, protractor

Protractor version: 5.1.2
Node version: 6.9.0
Angular version: 2.4.10

`OnPrepare` function i am doing `browser.get('/')`. After this i am doing a login in a `it`.
First issue is it throws error as **async function was not called**. After doing a failed research i added `browser.sleep(500)` then the above stopped to come and executed the login `it` case.

After that i have to click a button on landing page and then navigate to another page and click another button.Here also it fails saying that **no element found for the locator**.But if i add `browser.waitForAngular()` or `browser.sleep()`, then it starts to work.I can not add this explicitly everytime. Moreover when i worked with protractor(version: 1.3), it never used to happen.

So the problem I think is protractor is not waiting for the angular to synchronize.
Any solution is appreciated.

Protractor config file

```
exports.config = {
directConnect: true,
useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,
specs: ['./**/*.spec.js'],
baseUrl: 'http://10.209.1.38:9090',
framework: 'jasmine2',
capabilites: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
},
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 60000
},
onPrepare: function () {
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    browser.get('/');
    browser.sleep(500);
 }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code inside conf.js file and exports.config tag:-

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
```

And inside the login "it" use below code:-

```
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
```

And inside the other landing page use this code:-

```
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
```

Comment: you mean to say, i should use `browser.waitForAngularEnabled()` for every `it` cases?

Comment: No, for every synchronization, where you are moving from angular pages to non-angular pages.

Comment: my entire application is running in angular

Comment: In that case, Provide me your application URL and I will look in to this,

Comment: its under development :P

Answer (score 0):

Protractor doesn't necessarily wait for `onPrepare` to be completely finished, before executing the test.

However, you can optionally return a `promise` within `onPrepare`, which then Protractor will await before continuing execution.

See details [in this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482583/force-protractors-onprepare-to-wait-for-async-http-request) or the [corresponding Protractor documentation here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/827554148d2af8e3dc1fdeb4481bfb906a98d116/docs/system-setup.md#setting-up-the-system-under-test).

For my case I added the Login-Steps (fill username and password, click Login) to the onPrepare-function, which also creates promises and therefore triggers Protractor test execution to wait until onPrepare-Promises are resolved.

```
onPrepare: function () {
    var login_page = require('../page/login_page.js');
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    browser.get('/');
    login_page.enterUserName('user');
    login_page.enterPassword('password');
    login_page.clickLogin();
}
```

Comment: didnt help me bro....am still not able to understand why protractor is not waiting for the screen to load or finish some requests..  Anyways thanks for your answer

Comment: To put it in simple words: If within `onPrepare` there is nothing to wait for, Protractor won't wait. As you don't resolve any promise within `onPrepare`, there is nothing to wait for. Try with adding the line `browser.waitForAngular();` below your `browser.get('/');` and let me know, if that worked. (Basically protractor should do that anyway without adding this line, but there are some challenging constellations, so it could slip away).

Comment: also [check out this relatively similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46734826/8683679).