# Error while running multiple specifications in protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

Whenever am running multiple e2e test cases then i am getting error from 2nd specification on wards, the 1st specification is running successfully. What is issue?

Error:

```
Stack:
TimeoutError: Wait timed out after 3002ms
    at WebDriverError (C:\Users\veeranagouda.patil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:27:5)
    at TimeoutError (C:\Users\veeranagouda.patil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:238:5)
    at C:\Users\veeranagouda.patil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_mod
    ules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2107:17
```

Comment: Well, issue is pretty obvious here. You get `timout`. The possible reason for that is one specification allows for longer timeouts than the second one. Increase timeout and it should work.

Comment: I have increased a time from 3000ms to 300000ms then also am getting error.

Comment: Then you have to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the full description for it.][1]

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46581036/failed-wait-timed-out-after-30009ms/46587036?noredirect=1#comment80155047_46587036
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try giving browser.sleep(5000) after 1st spec and try